# accordions stylesheet edit

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I am using accordions for my website.The given accordions looks like :

[image]

I want to edit the accordions stylesheet.I had activated many plugins of accordions..Now i am not getting which stylesheet to edit..

I want the header part to be little bigger..Then font of the header..

can anyone tell me which file to edit to reflect the changes on website?
or are there any properties/classe..to make the changesin stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't mention what accordion plugin you are using, the only one who can find out which stylesheet-rules that gets applied is you.

The easiest way to do it is to use the developer tools in your browser. In Chrome you can see which styles are currently applied to an element and which file they originate from.

Right-click on the accordion header and choose the element inspector from the menu - not sure what the menu items is called in English, but it will be something along the lines of Inspect element, Inspect component, or something like that.

I bet your can do the same in the other browsers as well.

**What it could look like in Chrome:**

[image: What it could look like in Chrome]

For instance you see that the `.post-text p` selector gets applied, and that it originates from the file `all.css`

**And in Firefox:**

[image: What it would look in Firefox]

Comment: hi thanks a lot..i meant to say i had installed different accordion plugins..so wasnt abl to get which one to edit...now found out which one to edit..

The plugin that is to be edited is Accordion Image Menu

Comment: hey..i just got the plugin name ..am not getting where i need to change can you please tell me...if you know..
and which developer tools  ?

Comment: @pradnya Most modern web browsers have built-in developer tools. Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer all have them. I believe pressing F12 in any of the browsers will open up the developer tools. My example above is from Chrome.

Comment: I am using Firefox !14.0.1 ..and when i press F12 nothing comes...:(

Comment: @pradnya Apparently Firefox uses a different key for that. To open up the inspector use Ctrl + Shift + I. Select the element on the page you are interested, and then click "Style" in the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: @pradnya Added an image of Firefox to my answer as well.

Comment: hey sorry but small query..

If i change/delete a node from developer tool is it possible to save  it?or its just for preview purpose??

Comment: @pradnya From what I know, it is not possible to save it unfortunately. But I believe most browsers allow you to copy one or more elements, so that you can paste it in to your IDE and save it there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14136/discussion-between-pradnya-and-christofer-eliasson)